# Un « service d'hospitalisation à domicile » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, reformulation, santé-et-médecine, évolution-récente

Un hôpital avant-gardiste de Montréal a mis sur pied un programme de [télémédecine](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8371522/telemedecine)/[soins de santé virtuels](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/26559157/soins-de-sante-virtuels) appelé « [hôpital@domicile](https://jghnews.ciussswestcentral.ca/fr/les-patients-qui-participent-au-programme-avant-gardiste-de-lhgj-font-lobjet-dune-surveillance-a-distance-pendant-quils-se-retablissent-a-leur-domicile/) » où des patients hospitalisés peuvent être suivis à la maison pendant leur rétablissement. Dans un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/sante/2023-03-29/hopital-general-juif/le-service-d-hospitalisation-a-domicile-ne-cesse-de-grandir.php) on traite du programme et on titre :

> *Le service d’hospitalisation à domicile ne cesse de grandir*

Linguistiquement parlant, y a-t-il « service d'[hospitalisation](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8353943/hospitalisation) », pourquoi pense-t-on ou non que le terme permet cette extension de sens et sinon comment se proposerait-on de remanier le titre pour préciser ce dont il s'agit tout en maintenant l'idée du contexte de rétablissement/hospitalisation ?

Answer (score 1):

Comme "hospitalisation" signifie normalement une admission et une présence dans les locaux de l'hopital, je proposerais :
**Le service de suivi hospitalier à domicile/distance** ne cesse de grandir.

Answer (score 1):

En français métropolitain, le terme consacré est [ambulatoire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soins_ambulatoires). Voir par exemple [cette description de la chirurgie ambulatoire par le ministère de la Santé](https://sante.gouv.fr/soins-et-maladies/prises-en-charge-specialisees/article/la-chirurgie-ambulatoire).

Ce terme désigne le fait pour un malade de passer un temps minime dans les locaux de l’hôpital. Il me semble donc qu’une "hospitalisation ambulatoire" ou une "hospitalisation à domicile" serait un oxymore, donc un usage incorrect. Je préférerais "soins ambulatoires", "chirurgie ambulatoire", etc. (selon le cas).

Ce terme est relativement technique et son usage [semble relativement récent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=soin+ambulatoire&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3). Il me paraît plausible qu'il ne soit valable qu’en français métropolitain et pas au Québec (ni en Belgique, ni au Sénégal, etc.).

Comment: On connaît le terme ambulatoire depuis un moment au Québec, en particulier on avait le « [virage ambulatoire](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/200811/19/01-802086-en-plus-daccelerer-les-departs-marois-a-freine-larrivee-de-nouvelles-infirmieres.php) » du réseau de la santé etc. Le terme est utile mais note que dans le cas qui nous occupe la patient a bel et bien été hospitalisé, mais c'est son rétablissement après une certaine période d'hospitalisation qui se fait à la maison. Si on peut remanier la phrase présentée avec le terme _ambulatoire_ ça pourrait être une solution.